# Build string from variable-depth nested JSON values

Tags: json, recursion, tree, jq, recursive-datastructures

I'm attempting to follow all branches in a tree-styled JSON object to create one long, concatenated string from each branch. The number of children and the maximum depth per node are unknown, so the result must be generalized to any amount.

The data I'm working with is similar to the following:

```
{
    "name":"root",
    "children": [
        {
            "name":"foo",
            "children":[
                {
                    "name":"bar",
                    "children":[]
                },
                {
                    "name":"baz",
                    "children":[]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
           "name":"zoo",
            "children": [
                {
                    "name":"zar",
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "name":"zaz",
                            "children": []
                        }   
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I came close in [this jqplay example](https://jqplay.org/s/QA0f2qEE4S).

You can see this works in the naive case where there is only a single child. Where I'm most confused is how to "reset" the parent in the scenarios of multiple children. Instead of recursing
`root -> foo -> bar -> baz`
I'd want
`root -> foo -> bar`
`root -> foo -> baz`

Desired output from the jqplay above:
`"root/foo/bar"
"root/foo/baz"
"root/zoo/zar/zaz"`

I would prefer a pure jq solution, a general Bash solution would also work.

Comment: *Very* nicely asked question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your data structure is recursive, a recursive helper function is what's needed here:

```
def flat:
  [.name] + (.children[] // {} | if has("name") then flat else [] end);


flat | join("/")
```

With your input, the output using `jq -r` would be:

```
root/foo/bar
root/foo/baz
root/zoo/zar/zaz
```